# Is equality of the signed Euler characteristic of the moduli stack of elliptic curves and the sum of the divergent series 1+2+3+... a coincidence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, divergent-series

(1) The signed Euler characteristic of the moduli stack of elliptic curves is $-1/12$.

(2) The Ramanujan-sum of the divergent series $1+2+3+\cdots$ Is also $-1/12$.

Is this a simple coincidence or can we use one equality to prove the other?

Comment: Divergent series have no sum! The series $1+2+3+\cdots$ is what comes out when take the definition of the Riemann $\zeta$ function for positive integers and plug in $-1$, and $-\frac{1}{12}$ is the value you get from the extension of the $\zeta$ function to $\mathbb C$. That does not make it the sum of the divergent series.

Comment: Edit. Ramanujan sum.

Comment: There are several rigid ways to assign a number to a series in such a way that if the series happens to converge then the assigned number coincides with the sum. Abel summation is another. I don't know many details, but $\zeta(z)$ for any complex $z$ is so regular a sequence that it doesn't surprise me that many of the different approaches coincide.

Comment: There is an inclusion-exclusion principle for the Euler characteristic which uses the integer addition, maybe this could help. See : https://qchu.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/euler-characteristic-as-homotopy-cardinality/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is taken form [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/moduli+space+of+curves)

> The orbifold Euler characteristic $\chi$ of $\mathcal{M}_{g,1}$ is given by the Riemann zeta function at negative integral values as follows (Zagier-Harer *):
>   $\chi(\mathcal{M}_{g,1}) = \zeta(1-2g) \,$.
>
> By the expression of the Riemann zeta function at negative integral values by the Bernoulli numbers $B_n,$ this says equivalently that
>   $\chi(\mathcal{M}_{g,1}) = -\frac{B_{2g}}{2g} \,$.
>
> For instance for $g = 1$ (once punctured complex tori, hence complex elliptic curves) this yields
>   $\chi(\mathcal{M}_{1,1}) = -\frac{1}{12}$ for the orbifold Euler characteristic of the moduli space of elliptic curves.
>
> **Don Zagier, John Harer, The Euler characteristic of the moduli space of curves, Inventiones mathematicae (1986) Volume: 85, page 457-486 (EUDML)*

Comment: Could we make an argument which does not involve the Zeta function? Linking directly the signed Euler characteristic to 1+2+3+... I have mentionned the inclusion-exclusion principle in my comment above. Maybe this could be a fertile path.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon I don't understand. $\zeta(-1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{-1}}$ which essentially is the Ramanujan sum for $1+2+3+4+\dots$

Comment: You are right. Still I was hoping for a more geometrical approach.